# Passing variable in <button v-tooltip=""> doesn't accept different characters

Tags: php, html, vue.js, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I have problem when adding a variable with characters like + and , ~~ , tooltip just generate an error

[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

invalid expression: Unexpected token

```
 <button v-tooltip="'{$myvariable}'" >
```

Noting that it works when the variable contain normal text

Thanks

Comment: where are you declaring `myvariable`?

Comment: I'm using livewire with laraval, myvariable is just to give insight I'm using {{$model->attribute}}

Comment: Did you try to set it as { content: $myvariable } ?

Comment: Hi @MaxiGui , I have tried that before, and it's not working :(, whenever there is a character in the variable it generate the error

Comment: are you able to edit var before injecting it to tooltip ? If you are, you can try to replace the special char (Ex: + would be &plus;) as followed : https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref  Search for entity code in google, you will get some adaptation

Comment: I'm not able to replace it as, also it's unpredictable characters and the users are using the field for free text

Comment: I guess, you are controlling what does the users send... otherwise you would get free injection. So you may able to replace.

Comment: that's actually a good point, will try that. However it still a question on why v-tooltip doesn't accept simple characters ?